# SQL Server does not allow for firewall update - Error creating the Firewall Rule instance

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-cli

**Hello community i am running the below `ansible playbook` through `azure cli`.
Also i get similar results from an Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.**

Also i have raised a github issue: https://github.com/Azure/Ansible/issues/21

What i mean using Azure CLI?

Go to [Azure](https://portal.azure.com/):

> -> Create a new Cloud Shell
>
> -> Ansible is already installed
>
> -> create a new yml file. Copy the below script.
>
> -> Run the below playbook. With this command `ansible-playbook nameofyourfile.yml`
>
> -> The below script fails

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    resource_group: ansibleResourceGroupName
    webapp_name: ansibleWebAppName
    plan_name: ansibleWebPlanName
    location: westeurope
    server_name: AnisbleDemoSqlServer
    database_name: AnsibleDemoSqlDatabase
  tasks:
    - name: Create a resource group
      azure_rm_resourcegroup:
        name: "{{ resource_group }}"
        location: "{{ location }}"

    - name: Create App Service on Linux with dotnetcore
      azure_rm_webapp:
        resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
        name: "{{ webapp_name }}"
        plan:
          resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
          name: "{{ plan_name }}"
          is_linux: true
          sku: S1
          number_of_workers: 1
        frameworks:
          - name: "dotnetcore"
            version: "3.1"

    - name: Create (or update) SQL Server
      azure_rm_sqlserver:
        resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
        name: "{{ server_name }}"
        location: "{{ location }}"
        admin_username: panoskarajohn
        admin_password: Testpasswordxyz12!

    - name: Create (or update) SQL Database
      azure_rm_sqldatabase:
        resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
        server_name: "{{ server_name }}"
        name: "{{ database_name }}"
        location: "{{ location }}"

    - name: Create (or update) Firewall Rule
      azure_rm_sqlfirewallrule:
        resource_group: "{{ resource_group }}"
        server_name: "{{ server_name }}"
        name: firewallruleAllowAll
        start_ip_address: 0.0.0.0.
        end_ip_address: 255.255.255.255
```

My sqlserver is created. 
But the firewall rule fails, with an **`unauthorised error`**.

`At the end i have provided the errors`

> Also when i try to do it manually to add a firewall rule through the azure portal.
>   Everything is deactivated. Also the add client ip seems to be inactive.
>
> Also even with the choices i am allowed to change, the save button is unresponsive.
>   The whole firewalls page seems unresponsive.
>
> See image for more info.

**When i create through the azure portal a new sql server, everything seems to operate**.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Firewall Rules]

Error i get:

`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error creating the Firewall Rule instance: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url:` -> Some url.

When i click on the url i get this json -> `{"error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is missing."}}`

**Ansible Version** for my Ubuntu Machine

> ansible 2.9.6
>     config file = None
>     configured module search path = [u'/home/pkaragiannis/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
>     ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
>     executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
>     python version = 2.7.17 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:07:09) [GCC 7.4.0]
>
> **Ansible Output from Ubuntu VM**
>
> PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************
>   ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [Create a resource group] *************************************************************************
>   changed: [localhost]
>
> TASK [Create App Service on Linux with dotnetcore] *****************************************************
>   changed: [localhost]
>
> TASK [Create (or update) SQL Server] *******************************************************************
>   [WARNING]: Azure API profile latest does not define an entry for SqlManagementClient
>   changed: [localhost]
>
> TASK [Create (or update) SQL Database] *****************************************************************
>   changed: [localhost]
>
> TASK [Create (or update) Firewall Rule] ****************************************************************
>   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error creating the Firewall Rule instance: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/******-*****-*******/resourceGroups/ansibleResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/AnisbleDemoSqlServer/firewallRules/firewallruleAllowAll?api-version=2014-04-01"}
>
> PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************
>   localhost                  : ok=5    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Comment: Maybe you can try to add the AAD user or client_id in the task that creates firewall rules.

Comment: Which type of authentication? And what is the permission of the user?

Comment: Which role do you assign to the service principal?

Comment: I mean the role you assign to the sp. The sp should have permission to do the action.

Comment: What about the situation now? Does the advice solve your problem?

Comment: Still do not solve the problem?

Comment: How do you try the advice? Create the new service principal with the role assignment?

Comment: I followed this tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8aWeHCrGh4&t=1355s. Does the above script work for you?

Comment: It works for me. But I do not use the DevOps, just run the ansible locally and it works fine for me. Did you test it locally in the VM?

Comment: Hello Charles, no luck! I have updated the quesrtion at the end to show you the output. For the service principal i have used the tutorial above. I connected through ssh and ran the above script.

Comment: Also @CharlesXu please note i have done sth very similar with mysql and worked perfectly! I am very curious how it worked for you.

Comment: I just create a service principal and configure the credentials as it shows. Then deploy it as normal. Then the YAML file has no difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213074/discussion-between-panoskarajohn-and-charles-xu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to create the SQL server and the firewall rules for it, I see you use the service principal to authenticate. So first of all, the service principal should have the Contributor role of the subscription or the resource group that you would use.

Log in with the service principal, and then the Azure CLI command to create the SQL server and the firewall rules:

```
az sql server create -l westus -g mygroup -n myserver -u myadminuser -p myadminpassword
az sql server firewall-rule create -g mygroup -s myserver -n myrule --start-ip-address 1.2.3.4 --end-ip-address 5.6.7.8
```

With the Ansible, it should also work and I did not see any problems in the code. Just set the credentials for it with the service principal correctly.

Update:

Here is the screenshot of the ansible:

[image]

Update-1:

Here is the YAML file of above screenshot:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Create (or update) SQL Server
      azure_rm_sqlserver:
        resource_group: mygroup
        name: mysqlname
        location: eastus
        admin_username: username
        admin_password: password

    - name: Create (or update) Firewall Rule
      azure_rm_sqlfirewallrule:
        resource_group: mygroup
        server_name: mysqlname
        name: FirewallRule1
        start_ip_address: 10.0.17.62
        end_ip_address: 10.0.17.62
```

Comment: This is a proper workaround, this is why i gave you the correct answer. This is most probably a bug with ansible. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @panoskarajohn Maybe you can change a new environment and try it again with the steps with the idle time. The ansible also works here, so I also confused about the problem.

Comment: This is crazy for me as well. I will create a new env.

Comment: Also to answer the answer you asked before, what i mean i use the Azure CLI?
If you go to azure and create a new Cloud Shell. Ansible is already installed there. So you can easily run the above script. I mainly test with that because it is less effort from connecting to my remote machine.

Comment: Please Charles you say it works for you. Please post a screenshot of the ansible playbook results. i have updated my question for instructions to run the script on azure cloud shell.

Comment: You have been most helpful!

Comment: Even on different env. I get the same error. I have provided the full script on my question. Could you please also provide your yml script?

Comment: @panoskarajohn Sure! Added it.

Comment: @panoskarajohn What about it? Does it work for you and what happened before?

Comment: My bad.It still does not work for me. Honestly i am mind blown that this works for you. I just don't understand why. We have the same script. It does create the sql server. It just fails at the firewall rule.

Comment: @panoskarajohn It's so wired. All the things work without any problems here.